# Proof of every regular language has a LL(1) grammar

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars, parsers, ll-k

I tried some examples and found that LL(1) grammar always exist.

I tried searching for formal proof but didn't find any.

Can someone give a formal proof for the above statement?

Comment: Have you tried proving it yourself? You need to construct a grammar from a deterministic finite automaton.

Comment: Use the characterisation with FIRST and FOLLOW sets.

Comment: Express the corresponding  DFA as a grammar. Each state becomes a non-terminal. The transitions from a state become a production. Terminal states disjoin the empty state.

Comment: Use a left-regular or a right-regular grammar.